# What would be a good practice - Should I create a new object or reuse the same one?

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def ReadThis(TextToRead):
    speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
    speak.Speak(TextToRead)
```

I have two ways to go about it:

1 - Create the Speak object once, outside the function, and then use it again and again.

2- Create the object each time I call the function.

I'm trying to figure out:

A) Would it be much less efficient if I'll create a new object every time I call the function?

B) Should I delete/close the object at the end of the procedure?

Thanks...

Comment: You should time the options.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of this class. It may have some internal state that may or may not change after invocation of its methods, which in turn may or may not affect the behavior of these methods. So, if you _do_ create a new object on each function call, you may (or may not) get different behavior. Obviously, creating the object over and over again is more time consuming than creating it only once. So, that really depends on what the class does, how it manipulates its state and whether it even has one.

Comment: @DanD. what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an object is a (relatively) expensive process in terms of the time required to do so, as compared to calling a function for example, especially if this object is complex. If this method is going to be used repeatedly then it should be declared outside of the function, as this would be more efficient. This all depends on what your requirements are for your program of course. The garbage collector will take care of the object it is no longer needed in your program, so this shouldn't be a problem. I hope this helps.